# Image disappears as soon as i wrap it in a div

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I don't understand the behaviour of the following:

```
  <div class="ad-img">
    <img src="assets/pictures/SmartDriver.jpg" alt="Smart Driver">
  </div>
```

If i place my image inside the div container the div container with the image completely disappears. It appears in the elements section of the browser, but is not shown anywhere even when i hover the mouse over the element

I also give the div element a width and a height

```
.ad-img {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
}
```

Additionally:

This div is wrapped with a second one in a flexbox, whereas the second one with texts and buttons appears normally

```css
.ad-img {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="ad-img">
  <img src="assets/pictures/SmartDriver.jpg" alt="Smart Driver">
</div>
```

Comment: you need to post a link or more code. There are a lot of possibilities

Comment: set a working snippet to demonstrate your issue , your flexbox and the children and the rules attached ... is flex-grow involved is display:none involved , and so on. there is many reason that would make the image be shrink to none or not expand its parent ...

Comment: i turned your code into a snippet , please edit it and add what is missing to show us your issue, so one can help

Comment: could you please replicate it in some fiddles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is probably not due to the code itself, but rather by the **class name of your div**: `ad-img`, then somewhere in the rendering phase, a particular agent blocked it.

1st possibility: if you are coding in [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension activated, and test the code with `Open with Live Server`. It may have blocked the `<div>` before rendering the code. You can try to open the .html file directly in browser instead, to confirm this cause.

2nd possibility: a browser specific **ad-blocking browser extension** that recognized the `ad-img` class as an unwanted third-party advertisement, and blocked the content of the entire `<div>`. You can try to pause the extension and refersh your page to confirm this cause.

To avoid this issue, you may give another name than `ad-xxx` to the parent element that is wrapping your `<img>`.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
}

.ad-img {
    width: 20rem;
    height: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- AS FAR AS I CAN TELL YOU HAVE SOMETHING LIKE THIS. PICTURE, TEXT, BUTTON -->

<div class="box">
    <div class="ad-img"><img src="https://seeklogo.com/images/S/smart-driver-logo-7D11F819D2-seeklogo.com.png" alt="Smart Driver"></div>
    <div>Text in div 2</div>
    <div><button type="button">Click Me!</button></div>
</div>
```